# Referencing a new column without a fixed address in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to reference the column immediately preceding a column labeled "Total".

My macro is supposed to find the column labeled "Total", insert a row before it, and then loop through a SUMIF function for the specified cells. I got the inserting a column portion working, but I cannot figure out how to then reference that new column for writing the SUMIF to.

I am trying to get the reference where I wrote [[HERE]].

Any ideas on how to get this reference working?

Thanks!!

And for transparency, I got the inserting a column code from another user's question asked on here.

```
For s = LBound(sheetArray) To UBound(sheetArray)
        With sheetArray(s)
            With .Rows(7).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
                Set f = .Find(what:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = f.Offset(, 1).Address 
                    Do
                        f.EntireColumn.Insert
                        Set f = .FindNext(f)
                    Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
                End If
            End With
        End With
    Next s

'The above works.

    For s = 1 To UBound(sheetArray)
        With sheetArray(s)
            For i = 8 To 21
                Set criteriaDept = sheetArray(s).Cells("B7")
                Set criteriaSite = sheetArray(s).Cells(i, 3)
                Set criteriaTherapy = sheetArray(s).Cells("C6")
                    sheetArray.Cells(i, [[HERE]]) = SumIf(sumIfRange, cSiteRange, criteriaSite,       
                        cDeptRange, criteriaDept, cTherapyRange, criteriaTherapy)
            Next i
        End With
    Next s
```

Comment: You could just get the column number of the column you find "Total" in , as say x.  Once you insert a column before the Total column the new column will be column number x, since the Total column will have moved one column to the right and becomes column number x+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the column number that is the one immediately preceding "Total" (by "preceding", I assume you mean to the left):

```
Dim preCol as Long
preCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(what:="Total").Offset(0, -1).Column
'Now, you can use that variable:
' ...whatever
sheetArray.Cells(i, preCol) = ...
```

Note that you'll likely need to change/update `Sheets("Sheet1")` to whatever sheet has that column header.

Comment: Brilliant! I really appreciate the help, BruceWayne. This worked like a charm.

Comment: Okay, in trying to build this out for the rest of my workbook (versus the test sheet I was using), how would I reference the array of sheets in this? Each sheet has the header.

Would I just add `sheetArray(s)` in place of `"Sheet1"`?

Comment: For anyone who might find this later: I ended up just adding blank columns to each sheet in the array until the column with "Total" was in the same location for each ("OJ" for me) and the just replacing "Sheet1" with the name of my first sheet. Since "Total" is now in the same location on each sheet, setting preCol to that numeric identifier works for each sheet. Not pretty, but it is the best I can do for now.